# Timthumb return blank, Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

I have a wordpress theme with tim-thumb installed, the tim-thumb works fine when site was in local or in staging server (All images are shown as required). But when I upload this into live (Production server) into amazon dedicated server, it stop working for some specific images. Please check this link at [**Medisetter Image**](http://www.medisetter.com/wp-content/themes/realestate-4/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=http://www.medisetter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/di8MEA4ie.png&w=598&zc=1). It always return a blank. I don't know why. My guess is that it is a permission issue but I have recheck the permission with staging server it was same, **755**. Oncee I change this to **777** but still it did not work.

Any one can helps me to solve this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried giving it a relative path:

```
http://www.medisetter.com/wp-content/themes/realestate-4/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=../../../uploads/2014/06/di8MEA4ie.png&w=598
```

But it returns an error that "The file you specified is <= 0 bytes.".

Which means it IS finding the file itself, but is unable to read it?

Comment: Thanks for quick response Mikepote,
Please check the link in staging server [link](http://medisetter.aqbstaging.com/wp-content/themes/realestate-4/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=http://medisetter.aqbstaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/spheres-grafic-design-grafikoan-hd-300-p-2.png&h=945&w=945&zc=1), it works fine, how? The image and code is same in staging and live.

Comment: Please see the previous comment and say something to solve this please.

Comment: Basically I saw that png file are not showing. @Mikepote